# Image processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I took this from the Matlab help section:

```
text(size(I,2),size(I,1)+15, ...
    'Image courtesy of Massachusetts Institute of Technology', ...
    'FontSize',7,'HorizontalAlignment','right');
```

I don't understand how it works, could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: this is not really an image-processing thing, it is more of general matlab syntax, syntax mind you that is not very hard to dig up.  That is probably why this question was put on hold fyi.  My answer should still get you what you need, but try to be more specific next time and be sure to put in some work and effort before coming here or else people will ignore you for being lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html

In summary:

x = size(I,2)

y = size(I,1)+15

"..." is just the statmentment line continuation character in matlab (it is basically saying, do not end this statement here, but rather continue reading next line)

actual text = 'Image courtesy of Massachusetts Institute of Technology'

The next 4 arguments are name-value pairs (as described in the link above).  Basically, it allows you to grab a particular setting and apply it a value based on its name.

font size is set to 7 and horizontal alignment is set to right.